# Angular: AngularJS $injector.invoke equivalent to invoke injectable function

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In AngularJS, it's possible to mark a function as injectable and inject services into the function by invoking it through `$injector.invoke`:

```
function fun(myService, yourService) {
  'ngInject';

  // do something with myService, yourService
}

$injector.invoke(fun);
```

In Angular, is it possible to achieve the same? In other words, to:

- mark any function (not class) as injectable?
- invoke this injectable function with specific injector ($injector.invoke equivalent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `@angular` the only places you can use an `injector` in order to invoke dependencies are `@Injectable` classes (e.g component, service, directive etc...).

So, in Order to achieve that you can add a `@Injectable` decorator as the following:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FunService {

  constructor(myService: MyService, yourService: YourService) {}

  fun() {
    //implement fun
  }

}
```

Comment: Ah, okay then. Seems like there is no other way to do it anymore for plain function in Angular, i.e. we have to wrap it in a class as you stated here. Thank you. :)